# USB-C through dock connected monitor randomly freezes after waking up from sleep

Tags: windows, display, external-display, usb-c

My Razer laptop is plugged to a Razer Chroma dock trough USB-C.
My monitor is a Samsung Odyssey G7 plugged to the dock with a USB-C to DP1.6 cable.

Upon waking up, the screen freezes a couple times per second. Disconnecting and reconnecting from Windows session or rebooting fixes the issue.

What could be at cause?

Comment: Is the connection to the dock USB-C or [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface))? (A Thunderbolt port on the PC has a little symbol of a lightning next to it, while a normal USB port should have the SS symbol). Also can you provide a link to the model of the dock or a part number?

Comment: Also, have you contacted Razer about this? There could be a driver or firmware update for the dock which resolves the problem. You might want to check also the Razer Forum https://insider.razer.com/

Comment: If you have not made a driver and firmware update, there's little use in setting a bounty. If you HAVE done so, please specify it in your question, along with any other steps you have undertaken.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Everything is up to date, no firmware update ever and Razer softwares are installed and up to date.

Comment: I think it's more of a Windows issue to me.